# postgres ORDER BY - How to get the sort order to consider any letter being before numbers or punctuation

Tags: postgresql, collation

When I'm using an `ORDER BY` statement, the returned sort order puts punctuation characters and numbers before letters. So I'm getting:

```
;something
1something
something
```

what I would prefer, is if the letters were considered as coming before the numbers and punctuation characters for the sort, like the following:

```
something
1something
;something
```

I understand that `COLLATION`s define the sort order, and have tried a few (e.g. "en_GB", "en_US"), but it's not made any difference.

- What collation puts letters before numbers?
- When using collations, does a columns collation have to be defined when creating a table?
- Or can it be used just in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to change collation with `ORDER BY nmuloc COLLATE "<collation>"`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you want to sort. What if, there are more non alpha characters in the string like ";something:something else" what about white spaces? Etc.

Comment: Hi @stickybit . Thanks for your comments. Yes. I did try that with `ORDER BY name COLLATE "en_GB"`, but it still put the numbers and punctuation characters before letters.

Comment: I assume subsequent letters will have the same ordering as the first letter has. i.e. it uses the same `COLLATE` rules.

Comment: You should look if there is an ICU collation that fits your need.